# How can I change plane size with different screen resolution?

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop

Is there any way I could fixed the screen resolution? 
I mean if it played at 800x480,800x600, 1280x1024, 1280x720, or wide screen, the camera keep showing same scene, same height and same width.
Maybe by making the object bigger, or else.

Regards
Kajal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this.this one is for perspective camera.hope it will work.

```
    Camera cam = Camera.main;

    float pos = (cam.nearClipPlane + 10.0f);

    transform.position = cam.transform.position + cam.transform.forward * pos;
    transform.LookAt (cam.transform);
    transform.Rotate (90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    float h = (Mathf.Tan(cam.fov*Mathf.Deg2Rad*0.5f)*pos*2f) /10.0f;

    transform.localScale = new Vector3(h*cam.aspect,1.0f, h);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your Object Fit on Different screen resolution,scale your object relative to screen resolution.

Here is my code for Plane to fit on camera size:

```
    float height = 1.724f * Mathf.Tan (0.5f * Camera.main.fieldOfView * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    float width = height * Screen.width / Screen.height;
    Yourplane.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (width, height, 1f);
```

Comment: this answer is for Orthographic Camera but i used perspective camera.